# OpenType 'calt' feature behaviour between font tyles/weights OR how to make a glyph correspond to any other font next to it?

Tags: fonts, style, opentype, font-weight, bold

[image]I'm looking for a solution for my connected script font which has multiple weights in its' family (light, regular, bold)

**The problem:**
Individually, the styles work perfectly fine and letters/glyphs connect as they supposed to (I'm using 'calt' feature and it's great).
However, if I decide to change the style/weight of some letters in the middle of the word - the surrounding letters (ones that connect to the different weight) - disconnect! As if it was a "space" or different font next to them.

**For example:**
I've got "justaword" written in light style, then I decide to make the "a" - bold, like this: "just**a**word" upon that, the letter "t" disconnects from the bold "**a**" and this bold "**a**" is no longer connecting to "w"
Another example is in the image above - the "oks" one.

Is it even possible to keep the letters connected between different styles?

Would love to know the actual solution or at least ideas that might work!

A quick and more simplified example in the IMG.
[image]
Thank you!